# Windows SmartScreen run prompt - missing in April 2018 update?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1803, microsoft-smartscreen

Following the [April 2018 Windows 10 update](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2018/04/27/make-the-most-of-your-time-with-the-new-windows-10-update/), is the *Windows protected your PC* SmartScreen warning dialog missing?

[image: Windows protected your PC]

I have a small free app that uses ClickOnce for install/distribution, and it's always been plagued by this dialog after install.

Doing some work today, I found that the dialog was no longer showing and instead my app was silently closing after startup.

After some head scratching I went into Windows Defender and changed the *App & browser control* setting from *Warn* to *Off*.

[image: Windows Defender]

...and my app now starts up.

I tested this on two PCs, both of which have the April 2018 update installed, and found the same results.

This seems more like a bug than an intentional change since it essentially breaks apps that fail the Windows SmartScreen check. Can anyone comment?

Comment: Did you see the smartscreen.exe in system32 folder? May be someone/developer informed Microsoft that it is a false positive warning and the app is secure.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I have done some research and found another thing. If you locate your app in %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Apps and execute the .exe file directly, the smart screen pops up normally and you'll click "Run". After that, you can click the desktop shortcut and app will start. This is without turning off SmartScreen. Resources are rare on the Internet at this stage so let's keep an eye on it. Now I use GPO to avoid other computers getting this upgrade. And I'm pretty upset about MS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a TechNet thread, which handles this issue:

Microsoft has confirmed this is a known issue:

> According to our product team collection information and test, we can
> now confirm this is an known issue. And We are working on fixing it.
>
> [Karen_Hu - Microsoft Contingent Staff](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/profile/karen_hu/?ws=usercard-mini)

[Smartscreen prompt does not show for ClickOnce app since Windows 10 Update 1803](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7cbd16f5-526e-4b0b-a186-3ebf41b7b349/smartscreen-prompt-does-not-show-for-clickonce-app-since-windows-10-update-1803)

Comment: I have updated your answer to include the relevant information from your link.  In the future it would be appreciated, if you quoted and cited, all relevant information from any link you reference when answering questions.  Answers which only contain a link, even internal to the StackExchange community, are typically not considered to be helpful.  This is because if the link were to cease to work, then the answer which only makes a reference to the link, wouldn't be helpful.  Your corporation and understanding would be appreciated.

Comment: @Ramhound you're absolutely right. Sorry for my mistake!